# Can javascript variables contain anything?

Tags: javascript, types

I know they can contain primitive data types and objects. And since I've been programming in react, I know they can contain objects, components, and even json. Is there any limitations on javascript variables? var/const/let

Comment: Functions and presumably components are both just objects. JSON data is just a string. There’s nothing special about them.

Comment: They can't contain a river, or or the feeling of joy. Ir doesn't make sense to say they can *"contain JSON"*, if anything that would be a string or just regular arrays/objects/values. But they can refer to any value in JS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - You have the soul of a poet.

Answer (score 3):

Any *value* can be stored in a JavaScript variable. Values include:

- All primitives
- Object references

Almost everything is an object in JavaScript. Notably, functions are objects (including React stateless functional components [SFCs] and React components, which are constructor functions), and so a variable can contain a reference to a function:

```
function foo(msg) {
    console.log("foo: " + msg);
}
function bar(msg) {
    console.log("bar: " + msg);
}
const f = Math.random() < 0.5 ? foo : bar;
f("Hi");
```

You have a 50/50 chance of seeing "foo: Hi" or "bar: Hi" with that code.

There are only a few things I can think of that a variable cannot contain:

- Operators. E.g. this is not valid:

  ```
  // NOT VALID
  const op = Math.random() < 0.5 ? + : -;
  console.log(10 op 5);
  ```

  ...although it's easy to get the same effect with functions:

  ```
  const op = Math.random() < 0.5
             ? (a, b) => a + b
             : (a, b) => a - b;
  console.log(op(10, 5));
  ```
- Execution contexts or lexical environments, but only because nothing ever exposes a reference to them in code.
- Memory locations, because (again) nothing ever exposes them in code.

> ...and even json

JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are the way to address all objects. JavaScript is an Object-based language (String, Number, etc. are all Objects with different prototypes).

For example, a `var` can hold: true, undefined, null, "string", `template`, {}, [], NaN, 7, infinity, /abc/

There aren'y any limitations I can think of.